# How to assign GCP static IP to my Squarespace domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, squarespace

Last year I registered a custom domain (foo.com) on Squarespace which I haven't used. I'd like to assign the static external IP of a GCP VM that I have. I couldn't figure out from Squarespace's documentation on how to do this. Or is this something I'd have to do from GCP?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: Kumar answer is the right one. You need an IP on your service (VM, load balancer or whatever) to register in Squarespace. It's only a registrar, a mapping table between your domain name and your IP. Squarespace does not deliver IPs

Answer (score 1):

- If you are having a static external IP address then check whether that VM is running and it can be accessible.
- If you don't have a static external IP address then you can reserve it by using this official document [Reserve a new static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static). After reserving the address you need to assign it to a VM by using this document to [assign it to a new VM while creating it or to an existing VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#assign_new_instance).
- Once you have the Static external IP address then, you need to make the changes as per this squarespace documentation to [complete the connection by pointing the domain to an IP address](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/215744668-Pointing-a-Squarespace-domain#toc-step-2---complete-the-connection-by-pointing-the-domain-to-an-ip-address) .

**follow the below steps to point to an IP address, add an A record to your DNS settings.**

> A record can point your domain with a subdomain or without it. Follow these steps to add an A record that points your domain without a subdomain:
>
> 1.[Open DNS settings](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/articles/205812348#toc-open-advanced-dns-settings) for the domain that you’d like to point.
>
> 2.In the Squarespace Defaults section, click the red trash can to delete your default records. Your domain can’t point to another site when these defaults are in place. You can [always add them](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/articles/205812348#toc-add-preset-dns-records-for-email--domain-forwarding--and-other-services) again if you need them later.
>
> 3.Scroll down to Custom Records.
>
> 4.Click Add.
>
> 5.From the Type drop-down menu, select A.
>
> 6.In the Host field, enter @
>
> 7.In the Data field, enter the IP address from your provider.
>
> 8.Click Save to complete the process.

- If you need more information or support, reach out to this [support
  contact](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6058244?sjid=13349353373360433521-AP).